# C# best way to convert object to string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, object

I am stuck in something. 
I want to convert this object, which is a array of objects, into a array of strings I cannot find a good way to do that. Do I need to use a for loop? If someone can also tell me why these 2 methods failed, I will appreciate.

```
    object greetings = new object[] { "hi", "hello", "greetings" };
    if (greetings.GetType().IsArray)
    {
        //string[] arr = greetings as string[];
        //string[] arr = (string[])greetings;
    }
```

Comment: `var asArray = ((object[])greetings).Cast<string>().ToArray()`

Comment: The key thing to understand is that casting `greetings` to an array of strings is not valid. You don't have an array of strings. You have an array of objects (where all of the objects happen to be strings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string[] arr = Array.ConvertAll((object[])greetings, Convert.ToString);
```

Comment: My argument against this approach is that `Convert.ToString` is about converting (i.e. changing one type to another) - this answer does work, which is great, but it is a strange way to attack the problem. What you want here is casting (since the data in the array is _already_ a string).

Comment: `Convert.ToString` is just a convenient thing to use here, and when work on `string` object it returns itself. @mjwills if you face the dilemma of the word **Convert**, then you can define another, like `obj => (string)obj`

Comment: Yes, I think the cast is _logically_ a better answer. I am not disputing that your answer works.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include only objects that are strings:

```
string[] result = greetings.OfType<string>().ToArray();
```

If you want to include everything (non-strings throw an exception):

```
string[] result = greetings.Cast<string>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```
object[] objArray = { "A", "B", "C" };
string[] strArray = objArray.Cast<string>().ToArray();

//2.
object[] objArray2 = { "A", null, 1, false };
foreach (object obj in objArray2)
{
  if (obj != null)
  {
    if (obj.GetType() == typeof(string))
    {
      //strings values in here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. However, in my question, it is a object, not a object array. So, I cannot put greetings inside a foreach loop

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.